# Email not sending when new user registers using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have my User model that users devise and I have added a mailer to send myself an email when a user signs up. When I run my code, I get no error. In the command line, it says that the email has been sent but I don't get anything. What do you think is the reason for this.

My welcome_mailer:

```
class WelcomeMailer < ApplicationMailer

    default :from => "jasonbig@gmail.com"

    def welcome_send(user)
        @user = user
        mail to: "jasonbig@gmail.com", subject: "New user added", from: "jasonbig@gmail.com"
    end

end
```

Application mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "jasonbig@gmail.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  after_create :welcome_send

  def welcome_send
    WelcomeMailer.welcome_send(self).deliver
  end

end
```

Welcome_mailer view(welcome_send.html.erb):

```
<h1>Hello, <%= @user.email %> has been added</h1>
```

development.rb in config(maybe the error is in the smtp settings):

```
Rails.application.configure do


  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false


  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  # these options are only needed if you choose smtp delivery
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port           => 25,
    :domain         => 'gmail.com',
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name      => 'jasonbig',
    :password       => 'I have entered my actual password here'
  }

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

end
```

These are the only files I have related to ActionMailer. Please let me know if I have to add any more files or change something.

My command line email sent confirmation:

Comment: Does it log some message when you try to send an email?

Comment: On the command line, it displays the welcome_send.html.erb content.

Comment: update your question with the log. With the email content it probably appears an information about it...

Comment: And add this configuration: `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`

Comment: @ThiagoUruray I added the line you told me to add. Same problem. Also, stackoverflow is not letting me add pics right now. Some problem with imgur. But in the cmd line it says "WelcomeMailer#welcome_send: processed outbound mail in 587ms" and then they say "sent mail to jasonbig@gmail.com" and they display the sender info, recipient info, subject and then the content of the html view file.

Comment: Oh, gmail uses port 587 e authentication plain, see this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

Comment: In addition to other suggestions, you might need to use your full email address as the username, e.g. "jasonbig@gmail.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```

And I would add this configs:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

And see if you have enabled 2F auth in gmail

Comment: Hey Thiago, how do I check if I have 2F auth in gmail?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
  :port           => 587,
  :domain         => 'gmail.com',  
  :authentication => :login,  
  :user_name      => 'jasonbig',  
  :password       => 'I have entered my actual password here'  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Same issue. Is there any their any other problem you see?

Comment: in my code, how exactly is the body of the message been sent? (I'm asking this because I got this code by following a tutorial)

Comment: :authentication => :plain,

Comment: Did you get an email saying something like "A less secure application is trying to access you email account"?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
:authentication => :plain,
```

Additionally, if you have two-factor authentication for your Gmail account, you need to follow the instructions in this document:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
and replace

```
:password => LESS_SECURE_APP_GMAIL_PASSWORD,
```